# How we can access method and Variable in python having same names?

Tags: python, class, object

In the below code how can i access local Variable **name** instead of name Method.

```
class Example():
  name = "Its a Variable"

  def name(self):
    return "Its a Method"
```

if i try to do this
first  a created a instance

```
c1 = Example()
```

Calling a method **name**

```
c1.name()
```

'Its a Methond'

trying to access the Local variable **name**

```
c1.name
<bound method Example.name of <__main__.Example object at 0x7f430d8de490>>
```

Please help me understand, what is happening at the backend of this code.

Comment: you cannot overload in python ... the function name shadows the class variable ... it is no longer accessible to access the variable

Comment: The later definition of a name in a scope ‘wins’ by overwriting the previous definition - in this case the method `name` overwrites the class variable `name`. The previous definition is erased so it’s not even possible to access/use it by fudgery.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible in python. You'll have to change either the method name or the class variable.